# Negative values with different flags

Tags: assembly, flags

I'm trying to understand how negative values work with the different flags.
With this code:

```
mov ax, 0
add al, 116
sub al, 117
```

Now I'm supposed to write what ZF, CF, OF, and SF will be.

- Zero Flag will be 0  because the result isn't zero.
- Carry Flag will be 1 because I had to 'borrow'.

  The problem is in the worksheet I need to write why the Carry Flag will be on/off in the format: 'The carry flag will be on/off because the result of the operation is _______ (in base 10), and this value exceeds the range of numbers in 8 bits.'

I don't quite understand what the result will be in unsigned..

- Overflow Flag I understand it should be off but I don't get why.

Complement 2's: `0001 -> 1110 + 1 -> 1111 =  FFh`
FF is is 255 which is passed the range of `-127 - 128', so why is the OF off?

- Sign Flag- why is it on?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why the result can't be zero? If `al` was `1`, the result *will* be zero.

Comment: `OF` is for signed arithmetic in which case `116-117=-1` and that is within range so `OF` is zero. Also it's negative, so `SF` is on. It is however not in range of unsigned (obviously) so `CF` is on.

Comment: @Ped7g but the result is -1 so how can it be zero?

Comment: no, from the code you posted one can not tell, what is the result. The result will be original value in `al` minus one. (which can be any of the 0-255 values range).

Comment: sorry, you're right I'll correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result in `al` is `1111 1111`<sub>base 2</sub> (all eight bits set to one).

If you **interpret** it as unsigned 8 bit value, it is `255 = FFh`.

If you **interpret** it as signed 8 bit value, it is `-1 = -1h`.

As you can see, the value in `al` itself has no information, if it is signed or unsigned value, it's just 8 bits. The logical meaning and type is given by the code, which is interpreting those 8 bits certain way.

CF is unsigned math related, there 116 - 117 is "1 less than 0", which is out of unsigned range (starting at 0 for all possible bit sizes).

So I'm not sure what to write in your sheet.. probably -1, as that is the result in decimal, and it really exceeds the range of  (**unsigned**) 8 bits. Then again in unsigned computer math 0-1 is clear 255 for 8 bit values, as they wrap around by 256 (or other power of two for other bit sizes) (The 8 bit math is group-256 or how it is called in Algebra, doing 0-1 is then well defined and result is simply "255").

So I'm quite puzzled by that proposed sentence, if you will write `255` there, that's the correct result, but that fits into unsigned 8 bits nicely. It exceeds range of signed 8 bit values (only +127 max). But with signed 8 bit values the result `-1` fits 8 bits, so... I find this inaccurately worded, and I'm not sure what answer is expected. The CF will be on, because 0 - 1 = 255 (wrapped around → CF=1), but 255 fits 8 bits. That's accurate-enough for me.

OF is signed math related. It is set, when the signed math overflows. As you are doing 116 + -117, that's positive plus negative value. Both source values already were within 8 bit signed range (-128..+127). Then adding positive with negative can result into value which is between the original ones. If it is between them, it will surely be again legal 8 bit signed value, so there can't happen any overflow at all.

Overflow may happen if you add two negative, or two positive values. Then if the result has different sign than any of the source values, the overflow did happen (OF=1). I.e. negative result from positive+positive is OF=1, and positive/zero result from negative+negative is OF=1. Every other combination is OF=0.

In this particular case 116 + -117 = -1 → all fits into 8 bit signed values without any problem, OF=0.

SF is top-most bit of result, because unsigned 8 bit values 0..127 are interpreted the same way in signed 8 bit, but 128..255 are interpreted as -128..-1 in signed 8 bit, where the top bit is the negative value signalization, and the value can be though of as -(256 - unsigned_8b_value). In your example -(256 - 255) = -1, and SF=1 (top bit of 11111111 (top = left-most, the one encoding value 2<sup>7</sup> = 128).

---

You were already provided with http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt in previous question, which explains it all quite nicely? Did you read it through?

Answer (score 0):

SF turns 1 when the result is negative.

OF turns 1 when by adding 2 numbers having the same sign or subtracting 2 numbers having different signs,the result doesn't fit in your case in al